# How do I style the new places AutocompleteSupportFragment

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any reference on how to style this? I haven't found anything on the developer documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, get your fragment's view by:

```
AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
View view = autocompleteFragment.getView();
```

To get the `ImageButton` view of the magnifying glass icon:

```
  ImageButton searchButton = view.findViewById(com.google.android.libraries.places.R.id.places_autocomplete_search_button);
```

To get the `EditText` view where they write "Search" as hint:

```
  EditText editText = view.findViewById(com.google.android.libraries.places.R.id.places_autocomplete_search_input);
```